# Deal with timeouts when posting data -no ajax

Tags: django, apache, connection-timeout

The use case:

User makes order his payment gets accepted and his details are getting post to a django's view. Using these details django's view creates user and everything that is necessary (Username and password is provided by me). Then before returning it sends email to clients email with his data (Username and password for now).

But sometimes I get a gateway timeout error from apache(app is deployed on openshift). Because the user is created I assume that the timeout comes from the email sending part. How can I make sure everything went ok and inform the user? How can I make sure that if the email isn't sent I can resend it? What is the best practice at that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have timeouts with an API or Service, you should fire your POST / sendmail request with AJAX...

1. Serialize the whole form (like jQuery's serialize())
2. Send that data via AJAX (with jQuery's ajax())
3. Inform the User of success or error (alert() or jQuery UI dialog)

You can find a lot of examples on this website.

Another "dirty" approach would be to add the attribute target="_blank" to your form tag what opens your lazy request in a new tab / window.

Comment: So there is no other way right without using AJAX. What about resending the email?Cause the problem is the email sending.

Comment: Like I wrote up there - use <form target="_blank">...</form>